# Find a homogeneous linear equation in $4$ variables with $3$ given vectors as solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

I am thinking on a question of how to find a linear homogeneous equation such that $(1,1,1,1)$,$(1,-1,-1,1)$ and $(2,3,3,2)$ are solutions of the equation.So far I think I am after a hyperplane in four dimensional space which contains these given vectors,but I have no Idea about how to find the equation.Can someone please help me a bit.I think I am looking for the hyperplane spanned by these vectors.Please somebody provide me with an answer on this question,so that I can obtain a linear homogeneous equation with prescribed solution.

Comment: hint: Find a non-zero vector $(a,b,c,d)$ whose dot product with each of the given vectors is $0$. This amounts to solving the homogenous linear system with the given vectors as coefficients. Then $ax+by+cz+dw=0$ will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyperplane spanned by those three vectors has a normal vector $\vec{n}$. Each point in this plane has a position vector $\vec{v}$ which obeys the equation

$$\vec{n} \cdot \vec{v} = 0.$$

This is the linear equation you're after. I determined on sight that $(1,0,0,-1)$ is a normal vector.

Comment: how did you find a normal vector?

Comment: If you don't find it on sight, you'd have to solve the system of equations $x + y + z + t = 0$, $x - y - z + t = 0$ and $2x + 3y + 3z + 2t$; which admits an unique non-zero solution (up to multiples).

Comment: got it.............